# Producing lower bounds for $\text{trace}(A^2)$ for a positive semidefinite, symmetric matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Are there any lower bounds on $\DeclareMathOperator{trace}{trace}$
\begin{align*}
\trace(A^2),
\end{align*}
where $A$ is positive semi-definite and symmetric?

I am aware of the inequality 
$$
\trace(A^2) \le\bigl(\trace(A)\bigr)^2
$$
Are there any inequalities in the other direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $A$ symmetric positive semi-definite, we have

$$\rho(A)^2\quad\leq\quad \sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k^2 \quad =\quad\operatorname{trace}(A^2),$$

where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\rho(A)$ its spectral radius.

**EDIT:** In the book [Matrix Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521386322) of A. Horn and C. Johnson, appears the bound 
$$ \operatorname{trace}(A^2) \geq \frac{\operatorname{trace}(A)^2}{\operatorname{rank}(A)}$$
(see exercise 13, p.175) which is in turn slightly better than $\frac{\operatorname{trace}(A)^2}{n}$ :).

Comment: note that you can truncate the sum wherever you want to get better lower bounds (by taking the sum of the square of the $m$ largest eigenvalues for example).

Comment: Nice, we have a little competition going :)

Comment: Ha ha ha, this is great. +1

Comment: Related: [Prove $\text{rank}(A)\ge\frac{(\text{tr}(A))^2}{\text{tr}(A^2)}$ when $A$ is Hermitian](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72545/prove-textranka-geq-frac-texttra2-texttra2-when-a-is?rq=1).

Comment: Dear all, is the following inequality correct. Since $A$ is PSD then $A \preceq A^2$ the $trace(A^2) \ge trace(A)$

Answer (score 4):

$\langle X,Y\rangle=\operatorname{trace}(XY^T)$ is an inner product, therefore Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives $\langle A,A\rangle \langle I,I\rangle \ge |\langle A,I\rangle|^2$, or $\operatorname{trace}(A^2)\ge\frac1n\operatorname{trace}(A)^2$ when $A$ is an $n\times n$ PSD matrix. This is slightly sharper than the $\rho(A)^2$ in one other answer.

Comment: +1: sharper or not, $\frac{1}{n}\operatorname{trace}(A)^2$ is **much** cheaper to compute than $\rho(A)$ in general.

Comment: This bound is in fact exactly sharp, as it is an equality when $A$ is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: @EricWofsey you are right, but it is possible to do sharper :) (see my edit).

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. For any matrix $B$, $\text{tr } B$ is the sum of the eigenvalues of $B$, counting multiplicity.
2. If $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $B$, counting multiplicity, the eigenvalues of $B^2$ are $\lambda_1^2, \ldots, \lambda_n^2$.
3. Since $A$ is symmetric, its eigenvalues are real, and since it is positive semidefinite, they are nonnegative.